# Split listbox items and split without selected item

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, split, listbox

To explain what I want to do the below is an example of what might be in my `listbox` (three list items of text):

```
                            listbox
                     ----------------------
                     |  hello my friends  |
                     |  how r u today?    |
                     |  i'm here          |
                     ----------------------
```

I want to split my `listbox` items (splitting where ever there is a space) into a 2 arrays. The first array will be my selected item (let's say we select "hello my friends", it's only a example; maybe second or third item can be selected) split and the second array will be my unselected items array. Like this;

```
string[] firstArray = {"hello", "my", "friends"}

string[] secondArray = {"how", "r", "u", "today?", "i'm", "here"}
```

But I don't know how can I do this...
It's my code:

```
         string[] LBI = lb2.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();                
         string[] selectedItemSplit=lb2.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' '); 
         string jo = string.Join(" ", LBI);
         string[] sp = jo.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

Thank you for answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Verify that there's at least one selected item, to avoid exceptions.
- Insert in the first array the content of the currently selected ListBox item, splitting it using [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) (since we're splitting on a white space, no need to specify a separator: it's the default).
- Take all the non-selected Items ([`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Where%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) the Item index is not the current) and use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to flatten the arrays generated by splitting the content of each Item.

---

```
int currentIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (currentIndex < 0) return;

string[] firstArray = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[currentIndex]).Split();

string[] secondArray = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().Where((item, idx) => idx != currentIndex)
                               .SelectMany(item => item.Split()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I remember you Jimi. Your answers always work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the selected item using `lb2.SelectedItem` and split it as you are doing, then take the rest of the items (filtering out the item with an index of `lb2.SelectedIndex` by using a `Where` clause) and then do a `SelectMany` on the results, splitting each on a space character:

```
var nonSelected = lb2.Items.OfType<string>()
    .Where((item, index) => index != lb2.SelectedIndex);

var first = lb2.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
var rest = nonSelected.SelectMany(others => others.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```

Comment: But i don't select the first item for split everytime. Maybe second item will be select, maybe three. Is it work for all cases?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood! I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok, modified it to grab only the non-selected items.